# Tailwindcss hiding and showing a div not working

Tags: tailwind-css

I am having trouble with hiding and showing divs.

For example I have a div with the following basic code:

```
<div class="hidden md:block">
    Some content....
  </div>
```

So in theory that should not show on a small screen but should show on a medium screen and above.

My problem is that the div is always hidden.

Has anyone any ideas please?

Comment: Can you share working code and explain with output , and are the sure tailwind-css is setup properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is Chrome. I changed it to

`invisible md:visible`

and it worked. Tailwind authors take note!

But - and it is a big but - if you are using datatables it will present the data but no pagination, search etc.

Answer (score -2):

If that's in React, please replace the class keyword with className. Also, have a look at the md screen resolution and the screen resolution that you're manually testing at the moment.

Comment: Hi Evan, ( Not the downvoter). People would normally downvote , if the answer would better fit as a comment. Unless you are not sure about the answer, it is preffered to add it as comment.

Comment: It is not in React - just Tailwind. I did not down vote it as I have only just seen it.

Comment: Cheers for clarifying that :)